# Magento current store category listing with single depth or parent only?

Tags: magento

I want to retrieve the parent category only in current store of magento. I googled and get the result for all parent category with subcategories included. but want only parent top categories single depth only.

```
if(strlen(trim($primary_category_temp)) < 1) 
{
   $_categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories();
   if (count($_categories) > 0): 
        foreach($_categories as $_category): 
         $primary_category[] = $_category->getId(); 
        endforeach; 
   endif; 
}
```

Comment: if( strlen(trim($primary_category_temp)) < 1 ) {$_categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories();
    if (count($_categories) > 0): 
     foreach($_categories as $_category):
      $primary_category[] = $_category->getId();
     endforeach;
    endif;
   }

Answer (score 2):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active',array('eq' => 1))->load();
```

from this i get whole category collection

```
foreach($category as $cat)
{
  if($cat->getData('level')==2)
  { 
     echo 'my code';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you need use:

`Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getRootCategoryId()`

or

`Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()`

for default store

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$categories=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
                ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

This will only retrieve parent top categories